# Fiding $g$ such that $\int_0^1 g(y)\int_{y/2}^{1-y/2} \frac{1}{g(x)x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y <\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that there exists a measurable function $g:(0,1) \to (0,\infty)$ such that
$$\int_0^1 g(y)\int_{y/2}^{1-y/2} \frac{1}{g(x)x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y <\infty,$$
(I do not know if such a function exists). But up to now, I have failed miserably. Any suggestions?

---

### Brief comment

I noticed that choosing $f(x)=1/ \sqrt{x}$ we have that
$$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{y} \int_{y/2}^{1-y/2} \frac{1}{x\sqrt x} \ \mathrm{d} x\ \mathrm{d} y = \frac{\pi}{2} <\infty,  $$
however I have not being able to adapt this proof to $1/x^2.$

Comment: Numerically, it seems that $g(x) = \log(1+x)$ works, but the steps in proving it are more involved.